# C# should not acccept duplicate ID with first and last name

Tags: c#

Here is my code should not accept duplicate rows in DataGridView

This is my datagridview it's not taking duplicate ID's but taking remaining fields to duplicate it should not duplicate filename, Lastname, and profession also

![Image of DGV with multiple rows][1]

I need output like this

![Image of desired DGV][2]

Code:

```cs
namespace Bind_DataGridView_Using_DataTable {
    public partial class Bind_DataGridView_Using_DataTable : Form {
        public Bind_DataGridView_Using_DataTable() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            string idText = IDTxt.Text.Trim();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idText) && int.TryParse(idText, out int idValue)) {
                if ((table.Select("Id = " + idValue)).Length == 0) {
                    table.Rows.Add(idValue, fisrtTxt.Text.Trim(), SurNameTxt.Text.Trim(), ProfesTxt.Text.Trim());
                    //table.AcceptChanges();
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
                    cleatTxts();
                }
                else {
                    MessageBox.Show("Person Id already Exist");
                }
            }
            else {
                label1.Text = "Person Id should not be empty && must be a valid int value";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just like you re searching via ID in your code, you can search the table for existing last names and first names. Something like table.Select("FirstName = ? AND LastName = ?").

Comment: Not working as in getting an error? or not matching an existing name? are you able to add a breakpoint to see the contents of the data table in the debugger?